# BQL on custom DAC referencing SOOrder.orderNbr not reflecting current Order Nbr

Tags: acumatica

We have a test DAC called UsrNonRelatedScanField with two fields : *OrderNbr* and *ScanStatus*.

Here's our simple query to grab the correct ordernbr and assign it to a SOOrderExt field:

```
NonRelatedScanField lastScan = PXSelect<NonRelatedScanField, 
                               Where<NonRelatedScanField.orderNbr,                                
                               Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);
if(lastScan != null)
{
    rowExt.UsrNonRelatedScanField = lastScan.ScanStatus;
}
```

This logic is held in a SOOrder_RowSelecting() method.

**Full Method implementation**:

```
    protected virtual void SOOrder_RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        SOOrder row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
        if (row == null) return;
        SOOrderExt rowExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(row);

        NonRelatedScanField lastScan = PXSelect<NonRelatedScanField, 
                                       Where<NonRelatedScanField.orderNbr, 
                                       Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);

        if (lastScan != null)
        {
            rowExt.UsrNonRelatedScanField = lastScan.ScanStatus;
        }
    }
```

**Expected Results** : Get the current Orders scan status from lastScan DAC

**Actual Results:** Will populate correctly only on the initial order opened. When selecting other orders the old value is persisting **unless** I manually refresh the page. When manually refreshed the correct data comes in.

I haven't had any issues in the past with BQL queries, this specific query is not behaving as expected.

Thank you

Comment: possibly due to missing the order type field also as SOOrder has 2 key fields? without OrderType you could find other order type order records? You could also try putting an pxunbounddefault value on your extension field to see if this helps if the value should always refresh when selecting an order.

Comment: Could you please add the full code, which contains the whole method/event where you have added this code

Comment: I'll test and see if it works Brendan, that could be the reason.

Samvel, I'll add the full event handler to the Original question now.

Comment: @Brendan Just tried the PXunboundDefault with no success unfortunately. I'll continue to play around with the possibility of missing the order-type key field.

Comment: @Brendan I added the OrderType and the screen only populates the correct value on a full refresh. Attempting Shamilla's example now.